# Chrome Extension to Block Stored Links

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I am trying to achieve the following: cancel the event (prevent the page from loading) if the link matches one of the links stored in Google storage and open the link in incognito window.

```
if link exists in Google storage:
  e.preventDefault();
```

This logic is done in content script by binding the listener on the document object to intercept any links.

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
  document.body.addEventListener('click', onClick);
});
```

However, until I check whether the link exists in Google storage the page finishes loading. I believe this is because `chrome.storage.sync.get` is asynchronous and the page just finishes loading before `e.preventDefault()` can be called.

Similar discussion: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9237044/async-loaded-scripts-with-domcontentloaded-or-load-event-handlers-not-being-call[][1]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9237044/async-loaded-scripts-with-domcontentloaded-or-load-event-handlers-not-being-call%5B%5D%5B1%5D).

The functionality I need: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38619308/how-to-block-a-tab-from-opening-a-page-on-webnavigation-onbeforenavigate-event[][2]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38619308/how-to-block-a-tab-from-opening-a-page-on-webnavigation-onbeforenavigate-event%5B%5D%5B2%5D)

Problem with the accepted answer is that the page is partially loaded. I do not want to load the page at all.

How can I get the list of links ready from Google storage without asynchronous calls inside `onClick`? Or how can I achieve the desired functionality differently?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used [chrome.declarativeNetRequest](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/declarativeNetRequest/) API to redirect user listed domain names to https://google.com/gen_204, and [onRuleMatchedDebug](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/declarativeNetRequest/#event-onRuleMatchedDebug) event to get the original URL and open it in incognito window.